Test container fails to start on Macbook M2 using Rancher desktop
I am running Rancher Desktop on my docker environment and recently we have moved to test containers to run component tests. Already I have made rancher desktop run contaniner engine in "dockerd(moby)". But I am getting this error
Container startup failed for image docker-registry.ru:443/testcontainers/ryuk:0.6.0
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed for image docker-registry.ru:443/testcontainers/ryuk:0.6.0
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:359)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:330)
    at app//org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.maybeStart(RyukResourceReaper.java:78)
    at app//org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.init(RyukResourceReaper.java:42)
    at app//org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:232)
    at app//org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory$1.getDockerClient(DockerClientFactory.java:106)
    at app//com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClientDelegate.authConfig(DockerClientDelegate.java:109)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:329)
    at app//com.ringcentral.qa.util.TestcontainersManager.startAndFollowLogs(TestcontainersManager.java:145)
    at app//com.ringcentral.qa.util.TestcontainersManager.initializeContainers(TestcontainersManager.java:68)
    at app//com.ringcentral.qa.common.ComponentTestBase.init(ComponentTestBase.java:25)
    at java.base@11.0.21/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    .
    .
    .
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at app//org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:344)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:563)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:354)
    at app//org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wait strategy failed. Container is removed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:511)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for log output matching '.*Started.*'
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.LogMessageWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(LogMessageWaitStrategy.java:47)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:52)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:909)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:500)
    ... 88 more

My docker compose looks like this
# Docker Compose file Reference (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)
version: '3.2'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: 'postgres:13-alpine'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
      POSTGRES_DB: 'tests_db'
    volumes:
      - ../../componentTest/resources/database/db_init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh:ro
      - ../../componentTest/resources/database/define_db.sql:/scripts/define_db.sql:ro

  postgres-ca:
    container_name: postgres-ca
    image: 'postgres:13-alpine'
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
      POSTGRES_DB: 'tests_db_ca'
    volumes:
      - ../../componentTest/resources/database/db_init_ca.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh:ro
      - ../../componentTest/resources/database/define_db.sql:/scripts/define_db.sql:ro

  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeper
    image: 'wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6'
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: 'wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-0.11.0.2'
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9094:9094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "met.reporting.redelivery:1:1"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INSIDE'
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "kafka-topics.sh", "--list", "--zookeeper", "zookeeper:2181" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 4
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  sl:
    container_name: sl
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ../../../
    ports:
      - 18080:8080
      - 18081:8081
    volumes:
      - ../../componentTest/resources//configs/application.yml:/etc/sl/application.yml:ro
      - ../../componentTest/resources/configs/hdk.properties:/etc/sl/hdk/hdk.properties:ro
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: 8080
      MANAGEMENT_SERVER_PORT: 8081
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/sl-service/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - kafka

I have followed this https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/using-testcontainers/ doc. Have already configured docker.sock
ls -la /var/run/docker.sock


lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  daemon  35 Jul 30 12:45 /var/run/docker.sock ->
/Users/{user}/.rd/docker.sock

